# Find a Borel subset satisfying the condition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Find a fixed Borel subset $E$ of $[-1,1]$ such that 
$$
\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{m(E \cap [-r,r])}{2r} = \alpha
$$

---

I think it is the trickiest problem for studying Lebesgue measure Differentiability. Firstly, I came up with setting $E = [-\alpha r, \alpha r]$, but it does not meet the condition of ''fixed'' subset. It is so tricky that even my TA said this problem is "hard as hell".

Anybody can suggest any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a try...

For every $ n \in \mathbb N$ define

$$ C_n= \left[ -\frac{1}{n} , - \frac{1}{n+1} \right)  \cup \left( \frac{1}{n+1} , \frac{1}{n} \right]$$

We will use the following claim:

**Claim:** If $\displaystyle{ A \subset \mathbb R}$ is measurable with $\displaystyle{ 0 < m(A) < \infty}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1) $ then  we can choose a subset $ B \subset A$ such that $ m(B) = \alpha m(A) $.

**Proof of claim:** Define the function $\displaystyle{ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R}$ with

$$ f(x) = m(A \cap (- \infty , x]$$

We can easily see that $f$ is contninuous (moreover is $1-$Lipschitz).

Now, we see that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m(A \cap (- \infty, n]) = m(A)$$

and

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(-n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m(A \cap (- \infty, -n]) = m(\emptyset)=0 $$

Thus,

$$ 0= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(-n) < \alpha m(A)  < \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) m(A) $$

since $f$ is contninous, by the intermediate value property there exist $x \in \mathbb B$ such that $\displaystyle{ f(x) = m(A \cap (-\infty,x]) = \alpha m(A)}$.

So, it is enough to take $\displaystyle{ B = A \cap (- \infty ,x].  \quad \square}$

Using the claim we can choose $\displaystyle{ E_n \subset C_n }$ such that $\displaystyle { m(E_n) = \alpha m(C_n)}$

Define now

$$ E= \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$$

If $\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{n+1} < r \leq \frac{1}{n}}$  then,

$ \displaystyle{ \frac{m(E \cap [-r,r]}{2r} \leq \frac{m(E \cap [ - 1/n ,1/n]}{2/(n+1)} = \frac{2\alpha /n}{2/(n+1)} = \alpha \frac{n+1}{n} \leq \alpha (1+2r)}$

and

$\displaystyle{ \frac{m(E \cap [-r,r]}{2r}  \geq \frac{ m(E \cap (-1/(n+1) , 1/(n+1) ) }{2/n} = \frac{2 \alpha /(n+1)}{2/n} = \alpha \frac{n}{n+1} \geq \alpha (1-2r)}$

Let now $r \to 0 ^+ $ in the above two inequalities to get that

$$ \lim_{r \to 0^+ } \frac{ m(E \cap [-r,r])}{2r} =\alpha $$

Comment: passanger, nice! Please note a typo in the last equation. Also, while the lemma is of separate interest, and is related to the issue at hand, may I suggest that a more constructive approach could be of some benefit here (e.g., $E_n = \pm \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{n+\alpha}{n(n+1)}\right]$)?

Comment: @JonathanY.: Thank's for noticing it! I fixed it. Yes, your approach should also work! I didn't think about it, I just had in mind that claim, that's why I didn't think as you!Your though is really nice, constructive way to approach the problem!